# What is the constant $G$ in Newton's law of gravitation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, physical-constants

I know very little about physics. So, please forigve me if I ask anything wrong. I just read an article about gravitation. Where I saw an equation $$F = \frac {Gm_1m_2}{r²}$$ where $F$ is gravitational force, $m_1$ and $m_2$ are masses of two bodies, $r$ is the linear distance between the bodies and $G$ is [gravitational constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant). What is this gravitational constant? Can someone will explain it to me? A good explanation will be really appreciated.

Comment: Not sure about this question. It's interesting to think about and explain what $G$ is, but the wiki page is quite good already https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant

Comment: My only issue with the wiki page is that it calls it all sorts of things (Cavendish constatant etc) apart from what I ever hear anyone actually calling it: big G or Newton's constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G$ is a value inserted to make the two sides of the equation equal. If everything else on the right hand side has a value of $1$ (for example, you have two one kilogram masses separated by a distance of one metre) then $G$ is the numerical value of the gravitational force between them. In SI units the value of $G$ is about $6.674 \times 10^{-11}$.

As far as we know, the value of $G$ cannot be found from theory - it has to be measured in experiments such as [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavendish_experiment). Also, as far as we know, the value of $G$ is constant - it is the same everywhere in the observable universe, and does not vary with time.

For more details see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant).